# LINQ Compare two datatables with .except vb

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Here is my situation, and I could use some help.

I have three datatables. 1 and 2 are from querying a database, and the the third is a table that will hold a final formatted table.

dt1 has 8 columns,
dt2 has 5 columns,
and a final formatted dtJoined.
I have already added all the rows from dt1 to dtJoined.

Each table has a key ID field, I need to find the rows from dt2 that are not in dt1 and add them to the formatted dtJoined.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim query1 = (From a In dt1.AsEnumerable()
              Where Not a.IsNull("CustZ")
              Select a.Field(Of String)("id").Trim)
Dim query2 = (From a In dt2.AsEnumerable()
             Select a.Field(Of String)("id").Trim)
```

This works fine (as in no errors), I pull out the key field of each table so I can compare the datarow

Next I want to compare query2 to query1 and only return the id's not in dt1.

```
Dim notDt1 = query2.Except(query1).ToDataTable
```

This is where I get an error.
The error is:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Parameter count mismatch.

I have searched this error, and haven't come across anything I could apply to my situation. I am lost because each of the row collections only has one column.

If I can get past this error, my next step would be to join dt2 on the keys that were not in dt1 so I can get the columns that were removed from when I compared the tables.

```
Dim queryGetAllColumns = (From a In dt2.AsEnumerable()
                          Join b In notDt1.AsEnumerable()
                          On a("id") Equals b("id")
                          Select a).CopyToDataTable()
```

Then loop through queryGetAllColumns and add the rows to the formatted dtJoined table.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: So dt1 has 3 columns that dt2 doesn't have, correct? If so, you need to add those to the result set of query2, because I don't think .Except will work on 2 datatables with mismatching columns.

Like this:
dt2.Columns.Add("MyColumn", GetType(string));

Comment: Except he is using `.Except ` on the two queries which `Select` the same field.

Comment: Correct, I am using the .Except on the two queries which only have one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is you are trying to call `.ToDataTable` on a variable `notDt1` that is of type `IEnumerable(Of String)` which results from your queries. Just leave off the `.ToDataTable` as unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you NetMage, this helped solve the problem I was having.